# Firefox font-size difference with all other browsers

Tags: css, firefox, font-size, browser-detection

I have been trying to accomplish as much as possible without browser sniffing, but frankly I don't see how this one could be done with feature detection.

The site I am building has a global font difference in Firefox compared to the latest versions of Chrome and IE. Absolutely positioned content is overlapping and the font sizes are exactly similar.

Is there any way to deal with this without browser sniffing?

Comment: set the width of container divs to be as big as the largest case (FF)? creates extra space on smaller fonts but prevents overlap?

Comment: Is the font-size smaller than minimum font size in browser setting? Or did the user zoom text only? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages

Comment: @HC_ I am short on space so shrinking text is my only option.

Comment: @tsh I am seeing this from my own machine and my zoom level is at 100%.